# How to created an instance of Internet Explorer in java by using JExplorer?

Tags: java

I want to access IE functionality like click, navigate, forward, backward, filling a form etc. through java by using JEXplorer.

Kindly show me the code or the link to the code.

Comment: Just asking for the code probably won't get you a lot of answers. First try it yourself, then come back if you have a specific problem.

Comment: I have already tried the following alternatives:
1. By sending HTTP request
2. By using WATIJ library
3. By using HTMLUNIT
4. By using HTMLCLIENT
5. By using cURL (a command line tool)

But I haven't thorough knowledge of any of this so I couldn't succeed. Only after that, I posted a question here for the code.

Answer (score 1):

In the [programmer guide](http://www.teamdev.com/downloads/jexplorer/docs/JExplorer-PGuide.html) you can see few  example like this:

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame();
   frame.setSize(800, 600);
   frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
   Browser browser = new Browser();
   frame.getContentPane().add(browser);
   frame.setVisible(true);

   // wait until the browser is ready to work
   browser.waitReady();
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll get better results if you edit your question to include details of what you've tried. Ask for help to implement one of those specific solutions. Use HTML "pre" tags to wrap your code snippets, indent 3 spaces for syntax highlighting.

Show some of your code. Then we would be happy to help you. Few people use that functionality on a daily basis, so even those who have done it would not remember immediately how they did it, but might be reminded by seeing what you've got so far.

Tell us what you want to accomplish. You might get suggestions to do it a different way, which you might not like, but it will help us to remember the problem we were trying to solve when we last encountered the software you're asking about.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an alternative: [Watij](http://watij.com/). Another way is to use Jacob and play with COM.

Comment: Many persons have suggested me these options but have I haven't thorogh knowledge of any of these have already tried these but encountered problems.

Nobody has provided me the actual code. Kindly provide me a ready code.